# Telerik DataGrid: Expand Column Group on client Side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I feel like I'm missing something basic with Talerik's RadGrid for ASP.NET Ajax.

I have a DataGrid that has column groups. Everything works fine, except I want to have the whole header of each group to be a link that expands/collapses the group instead of just the little arrow.

I've modified the header to change it to a link that calls a javascript function, however I can't get the javascript right to expand the grid.

After playing around a bit I have this for the javascript:

```
function ExpandGroup(index, element)  
{
    $find('LondonGrid').get_masterTableView().get_dataItems()[0].set_expanded(true);
}
```

- Index here is the index of the group (0 based), it's passed
  through correctly.
- Element is the DOMWindow.

The code in the function is obviously wrong, what it does is just expand the first data item. What I want is a way of finding all DataItems that belong to the group index and expanding them. But I can't find a way to do it.

The link in the header is added by modifying the ItemDataBound event handler:

```
protected void LondonGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    var headerItem = e.Item as GridGroupHeaderItem;
    if (headerItem != null)
    {
        string html = string.Format("<a href='javascript:ExpandGroup({0}, this)'>{1}</a>",
                                    headerItem.GroupIndex,
                                    headerItem.DataCell.Text);
        var control = new LiteralControl(html);
        headerItem.DataCell.Controls.Add(control);
    }
}
```

I'm new to Telerik controls, and my asp.net and javascript are very rusty so any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I forgot to mention we're using the 2011 Q2 version.

Answer (score 0):

I found an ugly ugly hack that finds the expansion arrow button in the header and clicks it.
Very fragile though, and I can't make myself recommend this as an answer.

```
function ExpandGroup(element) {
   element.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].children[0].click();
}
```